# How to add XML data to Wix page?

Tags: html, xml, velo

I am trying to create a webpage or page element that will read and display the data from an external XML data feed. I can't seem to find documentation on their site that will help and I am very new to this.

This is the XML url generated: https://spacedout.ampsuite.com/xml/releases?cid=2&s_date=2018-01-01&e_date=2019-01-11&order=release_date&dir=desc&limit=10

And this is an example of how I would like it displayed: https://client.ampsuite.com/

Pretty much just the section under "featured releases" that lists current music releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wixCode backend function in order to do that. All you need is to use the wix-fetch API to get the data, then you can parse the XML using xml-js (which is a node module you can install in the backend).

In your client code you'll need to call your backend function and then inject the results to something like a repeater / table element on your UI.